# How do i add a value to javascript object with a function?

Tags: javascript, json, cordova, web

```
bender: function () {
       var context = {
                pageName: 'Chocolatte  candy'

            },



            partials = {
                header: this.globalPartials.header,
                tabbar: this.globalPartials.tabbar
            };

          addBackbuttonIphone(); 

        $(this.el).html(templates["monkey"].render(context, partials));
        return this;
    }

});

return monkeyView;

});
```

in another location i have a js file that has the following function

```
function addBackbuttonIphone () {

    context.backButton="#more";


}
```

If i just add context.backButton="more" in var context directly it works . However if i use the addBackButtonIphone function to do the same it does not work . I am sure that this function is being called however, it is not giving the "#more" value to context.backButton.

Please help

Thanks

Comment: Looks like a scope issue, your defined context variable is not in the global scope, so running your method is probably creating a global version and adding backButton to that and not the one you expect.

Comment: Why not pass the context as a param to your addBackbuttonIphone  function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

modify your function signature to accept an argument called `context`, like this:

```
function addBackbuttonIphone(context) { 
  context.backButton="#more"; 
}
```

then pass `context` into your function, like this:

```
addBackbuttonIphone(context);
```